# How to pass arguments in AddEventListener with OOP approach

Tags: javascript

I have a question. How can I pass arguments in addEventListener inside constructor.

```
class Todo {
    #card = document.querySelector('.card');
    #expandButton = document.querySelector('.sidebar__expand');
    #sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar')
    constructor() {
        this.#card.addEventListener('mouseover',this.fadeRow.bind(this, 0.5))
        this.#card.addEventListener('mouseout',this.fadeRow.bind(this, 1))
        this.#expandButton.addEventListener('click', this.expandSidebar.bind(this))
    }

    fadeRow(e, opacity) {
            if(e.target.closest('.card__delete')) {
                const button = e.target.closest('.card__delete');
                console.log(button);
                const siblings = opacitybutton.closest('.card').querySelectorAll('.card__delete');
                siblings.forEach(sib => sib.style.opacity = '1');
                button.style.opacity = opacity;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think it is way to define private variables in a class.

Comment: SO's prettyprinter does not like them :/

Comment: Do you mean `this.#card.addEventListener('mouseover',(e, opacity) => this.fadeRow.bind(this, opacity))`

Comment: yeah but how to pass opacity with bind method? is it possible

Comment: what you are doing is already correct, except in `fadeRow` method, the argument list should be `fadeRow(opacity, e){ ... }`.